# PHP constructor function single param

Tags: php, json, object, foreach, multidimensional-array

UPDATE: I am getting this php error: Trying to get property of non-object on this line:
    if ($card->name == $fileRef){

I'm constructing an Object in php using `__construct(x='') { definition }` and calling the function `$var = new Object('string');`

the constructor receives a string ie 'file' that is related to a corresponding 'file.php'. There is a catalogue of all available file.php for this class in a json file, which contains directory information.

And I am catching an error, perhaps with my syntax? ... Got me two days now, want to take a swing?

```
public function __construct($ctitle = '')
{
    $fileRef = $ctitle.'php';

    //Get the json card directory
    $this->cardDirLocation = 'thisismyserver.com/CardDir.json';
    $this->cardDir = file_get_contents($this->cardDirLocation);
    $this->cardArray = json_decode($this->cardDir, true);


    //Find the card listing from CardDir.json based on form response input and construct a Card class instance or use the main page (default)
    foreach ($this->cardArray['Cards'] as $key => $val) { //search through each card IS THIS MY ERR??
        if ($card->name == $fileRef){ //if the name matches a name in the cardDir.json file
            //Fill Values
        }
                    if ($this->title == ''){ //or if there is no title
            $this->title = 'Get Started at The Home Page'; //refer to default values -> the home page
            $this->dir = 'cards/start/';
            $this->name = 'start.php'; ...etc
```

**The Err:** I can't get the $fileRef variable to match up with anything in the json file array, so it always goes into the 'else if' default. 
the json file looks something like this:

> {"Cards":[{"title":"Something",
>              "name":"file.php",
>              "dir":"somefile/dir/here/"
>             },
>             {"title":"Different than something",
>              "name":"xfiles.php",
>              "dir":"somefile/dir/there/" ...etc

Comment: What is output on the line `echo: $val['name']`?

Comment: Thanks This has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to loop through your entire array before returning or setting a catchall case. Here is how to do so:

```
foreach ($this->cardArray['Cards'] as $card) {
    if ($card->name == $fileRef) {
    // Your success actions here
     return true;
    }
}
 // Your failure actions here. This will only be reached if the foreach loop found nothing.
```

Comment: Explosion Pills: the debug echo statement output start.php (what I wanted) It was not matching up in the foreach.

Sabastien: yes you are absolutely correct. I made a human mistake and you caught that, as did I just as I posted the question. I will make some changes and keep posted *

Comment: Your output of start.php is to be done after the foreach regardless of what happpens. Otherwise, your foreach will only span the first element of the array.

Comment: The Problem was in the syntax of the if else and what I wanted output.

I also had to access the decoded json as such
    $this->cardArray['Cards'] as $card=>$val ...
    $this->name = $val['name'];